# Entity Framework Timeout when called from WCF

Tags: entity-framework

I have a .NET project that consists of the following:

1. WCF web service
2. Entity Framework data layer

The ultimate issue described below is with the User table. The User table the schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [AuthenticationKey] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT (1),
    [Admin] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    [AutoSubmit] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT(0))

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User] ON [dbo].[User] 
(
        [Username] ASC
)
```

If I run a query against the User table with 3 records in it, it executes in less than a second.

I am running the following query against Entity Framework in a method called User.Validate().

```
database.User.Where(user => user.Username == userName && user.Active).SingleOrDefault()
```

The above code executes ok when calling from a unit test. However, when calling from that method from a WCF web service, the following exception occurs:

*System.ServiceModel.FaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out*

Under the covers of Entity Framework, the below query is what is run when the query timed out. If I run the query it executes in less than a second. What might be causing this timeout?

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
[Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
[Extent1].[AuthenticationKey] AS [AuthenticationKey], 
[Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
[Extent1].[Admin] AS [Admin], 
[Extent1].[AutoSubmit] AS [AutoSubmit]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Username] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='test1'
```

Comment: Have you configured connection string for the WCF services correctly? And without writing a unit test try to execute an integration test to check whether it's working?

Comment: Have you enabled lazy loading ? this may be a serialization issue with the WCF service. Just try disabling it.

Comment: @Jayantha The connection string is the same for the service as in the unit test project. In the service if I was to execute a EF query against another table, it works. One thing to add is I converted the WCF service to a SOAP ASMX web service and had the same issue.

I did not enable lazy loading.

Comment: I have this very same issue.  I've seen some replies in other forums saying to run `exec sp_updatestats` on the database but this doesn't seem to have stopped the issue from happening.